# .csv to MS Word/Excel/PDF reporting tool for .NET

Tags: .net

Is there any open-source free tool to export .csv data to MS Word or Excel or PDF? It should also effectively generate a multi-page report.

Comment: what kind of multi-page report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPPlus - advanced open source library, that can generate Excel 2007/2010 files. [[link]](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Also, you may like [fyiReporting](http://www.fyireporting.com/) (Apache License)

Here is the quote from the site:

> The fyiReporting RDL Project is a
>   powerful report and charting system
>   based on  Report Definition Language
>   (RDL).  Tabular, free form, matrix,
>   charts are fully  supported.  Report
>   output may be displayed as HTML, PDF,
>   Excel, RTF, XML, .Net  Control, Web
>   Archive, and to a printer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Excel itself (or OpenOffice Calc, if you insist on "Open Source") to read you CSV and create a report?

Comment: Because Excel won't calculate sum of a column on each page and won't carry forward previous page's sum to next page.

Comment: @RPK: if I had this issue to solve, I would use Excel-VBA to solve it, but agreed, that does not work not out-of-the-box (wondering if other reporting engines support this directly).